# Application not terminated after all code executed

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I'm about to learn the java threading facility.

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new ExecuteTimer(Thread.currentThread()), 2000);

        try {
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("timer stopped");
        }
        System.out.println("try block executed");
    }
}
```

and the timer class:

```
public class ExecuteTimer extends TimerTask {
    public ExecuteTimer(Thread thread) {
        creatingThread = thread;
    }
    private Thread creatingThread;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm executed!");
        creatingThread.interrupt();

    }

}
```

When I debug the code. I have following output:

```
I'm executed!
timer stopped
try block executed
```

Everything seems to be final except the app didn't exit after I have the output above. The eclipse remain in debug mode and no exception has been thrown.

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().join();` - aren't you just joining the current thread, which effectively does nothing?  You need to get access to the thread that was created by `timer.schedule`.

Comment: @mellamokb I'm about to join the current thread. And interrupt current thread with another thread(It have the reference to current thread). Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you no longer need the Timer to run tasks, you should call `timer.cancel()` to release its thread.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I've called cancel method after the catch block. But the program is still running. Strange.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry I called the cancel method on TimerTask object. I've just tried the cancel method of Timer object. It works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use `thread.setDaemon(true)` to tell the JVM to make the thread a daemon thread. **Daemon threads do not prevent the program from exiting.**

Comment: While this might technically work, this is kind of hacking the intended Daemon thread functionality to mask the real issue. If anything important is going on in the thread, it will just die when the program exits - no cleanup will be done, like releasing resource handles.